# SQL query doesn't work when converted to VBA code

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I am trying to convert my SQL query to VBA code, and after conversion, when I run my macro in excel, it is not showing up any results. I just made some basic changes to VBA code. Any one can provide me a insight. I am using SQL server. Thanks in Advance !

```
 objMyCmd.CommandText = "SELECT c1.[RDT_FileID], C1.[Master Policy Number], c1.[Work item /Submission no#],c1.[Insured Name], c1.[Credited Office]," & _
                                " c1.[Credited Underwriter], c1.[Product Line], c1.[Product Line Subtype], c1.[Current Status], c1.[Effective Date], c1.[Expiry Date], c1.[Original Currency],  c1.[Premium in Local Currency] " & _
                            " FROM  Actuarial.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a " & _
                                " left join " & _
                                "( SELECT b.[Current Status], a.* FROM" & _
                                "( SELECT [Master Policy Number],SUM(CAST([Premium in Local Currency] AS numeric)) AS SumPremium, MAX([Work item /Submission no#]) AS MaxSubmissionNumber" & _
                                " FROM  IT.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record " & _
                                " WHERE [Master Policy Number] IS NOT NULL AND [Master Policy Number] <> ''" & _
                                " Group by [Master Policy Number] ) a" & _
                                " INNER JOIN IT.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record b on a.[MaxSubmissionNumber] = b.[Work item /Submission no#]" & _
                                " WHERE [Current Status] = 'Cancellation' and SumPremium = 0 " & _
                                "  ) c2 on c1.[Master Policy Number] = c2.[Master Policy Number]" & _
                                " WHERE c2.[Master Policy Number] Is Null " & _
                                " AND c1.[RDT_FileID] is null " & _
                                " AND c1.[Product Line Subtype] <>  '0102-Marine' " & _
                                " AND c1.[Master Policy Number] NOT LIKE '___PRI__________'" & _
                                " AND c1.[Master Policy Number] NOT LIKE '___BLA__________'" & _
                                " AND c1.[Effective Date] >= '2014-04-01' " & _
                                " AND c1.[Effective Date] >= " & PED(0) - 2 & " and c1.[Effective Date] <= " & PED(1) - 2 & " " & _
                                " AND c1.[Current Status] ='Bound' " & _
                                " ORDER BY c1.[Effective Date] ASC"
```

and my SQL query is as follows:-

```
            select 
                   c1.[RDT_FileID],
                   C1.[Master Policy Number],
                   c1.[Work item /Submission no#],
                   c1.[Insured Name],
                   c1.[Credited Office],
                   c1.[Product Line Subtype],
                   c1.[Effective Date],
                   c1.[Current Status], 
                   c1.[Premium in Local Currency]
            from IT.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record c1
            left join
                   (
                   select 
                          b.[Current Status],
                          a.*
                   from 
                   (
                   select
                          [Master Policy Number],
                          sum(cast([Premium in Local Currency] as numeric)) as SumPremium,
                          max([Work item /Submission no#]) as MaxSubmissionNumber
                   from Actuarial.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record
                   where [Master Policy Number] is not null and [Master Policy Number] <> ''
                   group by
                          [Master Policy Number]
                          ) a
                   inner join IT.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record b on a.[MaxSubmissionNumber] = b.[Work item /Submission no#]
                   where [Current Status] = 'Cancellation' and SumPremium = 0
                   ) c2 on c1.[Master Policy Number] = c2.[Master Policy Number]
            where 
                   c1.[Effective Date] >= '2016-01-01' 
                   and c1.[Effective Date] <= '2017-01-01'
                   and C1.[Current Status] = 'Bound'
                   and c1.[Credited Office]= '002 - New York'
                   and c1.[Product Line Subtype] <> '0102-Marine'
                   and c1.[Master Policy Number] NOT LIKE  '___PRI__________'
                   and c1.[Master Policy Number] NOT LIKE  '___BLA__________'
                   and c1.[RDT_FileID] is null
                   and c2.[Master Policy Number] is null
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot to comprehend. How about using a bit simpler example in vba (stuff like "select * from table") and construct it from there. Just to verify the underlying call mechanism is working as it should

Comment: What backend DBMS is this? MS Access? SQL Server? And consider saving such a query as view in the backend. Stored queries are optimized, cached for best plan compared to scripted string queries.

Comment: You mean like call a stored Procedure ?

Comment: By the way they are not the exact same queries. See `WHERE` clause date filters.

Comment: I have modified my sql query based on actual filters I need.

Comment: What are the values in `PED(0)` and `PED(1)`?

Comment: You have the wrong alias in `Actuarial.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a`.  `c1` is never defined.

Comment: You switched `Actuarial` and `IT` dbs references in first from and first subquery with group by.

Comment: If you assign your query to a string variable and debug.print the variable before running the query, you can check whether the query that is being sent to the DB is what you want and doesn't need any characters escaping.

Answer (score 1):

There are many differences and notes about your code, some are here:
I think you need to change your query string as follow:

```
objMyCmd.CommandText = "" & _ 
    "SELECT" & _
        " c1.[RDT_FileID]," & _
        " c1.[Master Policy Number]," & _                'Edit C1 to c1 => in newest version of SQL Server case-sensitivity is important
        " c1.[Work item /Submission no#]," & _
        " c1.[Insured Name]," & _
        " c1.[Credited Office]," & _
        " c1.[Credited Underwriter]," & _ 
        " c1.[Product Line]," & _ 
        " c1.[Product Line Subtype]," & _ 
        " c1.[Current Status]," & _ 
        " c1.[Effective Date]," & _ 
        " c1.[Expiry Date]," & _ 
        " c1.[Original Currency]," & _ 
        " c1.[Premium in Local Currency] " & _
    " FROM IT.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record c1 " & _ 'Edit `Actuarial.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a` to `IT.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record c1`
        " left join (" & _ 
            " SELECT " & _ 
                 " b.[Current Status]," & _ 
                 " a.*" & _ 
            " FROM (" & _ 
                " SELECT " & _ 
                    " [Master Policy Number]," & _ 
                    " SUM(CAST([Premium in Local Currency] AS numeric)) AS SumPremium," & _ 
                    " MAX([Work item /Submission no#]) AS MaxSubmissionNumber" & _
                " FROM Actuarial.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record " & _  'Edit IT.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record to Actuarial.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record
                " WHERE [Master Policy Number] IS NOT NULL AND [Master Policy Number] <> ''" & _
                " Group by" & _ 
                    " [Master Policy Number] ) a" & _
            " INNER JOIN IT.dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record b on a.[MaxSubmissionNumber] = b.[Work item /Submission no#]" & _
            " WHERE [Current Status] = 'Cancellation' and SumPremium = 0 " & _
            " ) c2 on c1.[Master Policy Number] = c2.[Master Policy Number]" & _
    " WHERE " & _ 
        " c2.[Master Policy Number] Is Null " & _
        " AND c1.[RDT_FileID] is null " & _
        " AND c1.[Product Line Subtype] <>  '0102-Marine' " & _
        " AND c1.[Master Policy Number] NOT LIKE '___PRI__________'" & _
        " AND c1.[Master Policy Number] NOT LIKE '___BLA__________'" & _
        " AND c1.[Effective Date] >= '2014-04-01' " & _         'I think you should remove this line
        " AND c1.[Effective Date] >= '" & PED(0) - 2 $ "' " & _   'Add `'` around a string input
        " and c1.[Effective Date] <= '" & PED(1) - 2 & "' " & _   'Add `'` around a string input
        " AND c1.[Current Status] ='Bound' " & _
        " AND c1.[Credited Office]= '002 - New York' " & _        'Add this missing criteria
    " ORDER BY c1.[Effective Date] ASC"
```

> Note: You can use `COALESCE([Master Policy Number], '') <> ''` instead of `[Master Policy Number] IS NOT NULL AND [Master Policy Number] <> ''`.

> Note: There's a very bad design in your date filtering, If you have `datetime` field in your database I recommend you to use `CAST([Effective Date] as date) >= '20160101'`.

HTH ;)